# Just a basic limit of a function

Tags: analysis, limits

Find this limit,and if you can, do it without derivates or integrals or l'Hospital , just using the fundamental limits of functions.
$$\lim_{x\to1} \left( \frac{x}{x-1} - \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \right)$$

Comment: I vaguely remember someone asking how to compute this limit without taylor series and l'Hõpital a few weeks ago.

Comment: How are you defining $ln$ is the real question...

Comment: The answer is $1/2$ but it takes 2 L'Hospital applications. Not sure how to do this without Taylor or L'Hospital...